# How to add a row to a table, using only strings from another table as reference

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have 3 tables Subject, Student, Enrollment

STUDENT table                             
idstudent        student_name
346                     Sam Smith 
454                     Tylor Cage
579                     Max Goodwin

SUBJECT table                             
idsubject        subject_name
401                     Math 
301                     Science

ENROLLMENT table                             
idsubject        idstudent       Quarter      final_grade
401                 346               1Q               A

301                  454               1Q               B

How to add Max Goodwin’s enrollment in Math class to the Enrollment table for the 2nd Quarter. But  only specifying names (e.g. “Max Goodwin”, “Math”) and not numbers (e.g. idstudent, idsubject) in the  statement in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an insert-select:

```
INSERT INTO enrollment(sdsubject, idstudent, Quarter, final_grade)
SELECT
  sub.idsubject,
  stu.idstudent
  '2Q',
  null
FROM
  student stu
  CROSS JOIN
  subject sub
WHERE
  stu.student_name = 'Max Goodwin' AND
  sub.subject_name = 'Math'
```

But it's perhaps not entirely wise, given that the names (in particular) aren't guaranteed to be unique like the id is (lot of Max Goodwins in the world) - unless you want to enroll them all, of course!

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries which return the ids:

```
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT (idsubject, idstudent, Quarter) VALUES
(
  (SELECT idsubject FROM (SELECT idsubject FROM SUBJECT WHERE subject_name = 'Math') t),
  (SELECT idstudent FROM (SELECT idstudent FROM STUDENT WHERE student_name = 'Max Goodwin') t),
  '2Q'
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aV9dMsGHnMXZF8xJZ8Pnv6/0).